# Having problems with splitting a String into max 1Mb size subStrings

Tags: java, string

I have to split a String into 1Mb size strings. With using `UTF-8` as character encoding, some letters take up more than 1 byte, so for avoiding to split a character in the middle (for example 'á' is 2 byte, so can't 1 byte go to the end of one String, and 1 to the beggining of the next String)

```
public static List<String> cutString3(String original, int chunkSize, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    final int end = original.length();
    int from = 0;
    int to = 0;
    do {
        to = (to + chunkSize > end) ? end : to + chunkSize;
        String chunk = original.substring(from, to); // get chunk
        while (chunk.getBytes(encoding).length > chunkSize) { // cut the chunk from the end
            chunk = original.substring(from, --to);
        }
        strings.add(chunk); // add chunk to collection
        from = to; // next chunk
    } while (to < end);
    return strings;
}
```

I'm using the above method to generate an example String:

```
private static String createDataSize(int msgSize) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(msgSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < msgSize; i++) {
        sb.append("a");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Calling the method as the following:

```
String exampleString = createDataSize(1024*1024*3);
cutString(exampleString, 1024*1024, "UTF-8");
```

It has no problems, I get back 3 Strings, as the 3 megabyte String was splitted into 3, 1 megabyte String. But if I change the `createDataSize()` method's `char` to append `'á'` to the example String, so it only stands from "áááááá..." the inner while loop in the `cutString` method takes forever, since it's removing every 'á' one by one, until it fits into the given size. How can I improve the inner while, or come up with something similiar solution? The String can be smaller than 1 megabyte, just not bigger!

Comment: You're problem is a bit odd - why would you want to work with a `String` in the first place if you know you're working in UTF-8? Using substring + encoding so many times is what's killing you (essentially going over the string in powers instead linearly), but if you know from the get go you're using UTF-8, what's the point? Can you elaborate how do you plan on reading the char data?

Answer (score 0):

Using the binary search logic would clearly fit your need.

Simply decrement faster, using only the half of the chunk size, if you still as some room, add an half of it, if not, remove and half. And so on.

A simpler solution would be to remove only the differences between `chunk.getBytes(encoding).length` and `chunkSize`. Then see how many byte you can still take if you want to fill it completly.